# Repeator in VisualStudio ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, repeater

I am using Repeater Control in ASP.Net. But i get a lot of errors if i try to bind any thing to text field or like that because of double quote (").

its like

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "orderid") %>
     <hr>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "orderdate") %>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <SeparatorTemplate>
    <br>
  </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

if i want that text field should also be repeated and orderid and orderdate should
come in text field. What is the best way of that.

Regards
Atif

Comment: You say "because of double quote (")." - what exactly does that mean?

Comment: forget it, just let me know i want table column values coming from table and shown in a text field, repetitively ,any idea?

Comment: forget it? Your question is not clear. If you are looking for good answers, clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this...

```
  <ItemTemplate>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "orderid").ToString().Replace("\"", "'") %>
     <hr>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "orderdate").ToString().Replace("\"", "'") %>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I asked, what if i want to show  value in text box, repetitively, like a table has record atif, naveed, butt,   it should print 3 text fields with text in it, atif, naveed, butt.